# Extra Large size file upload Doesn't working using PHP/HTML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I don't want to restrict user to upload large file. User can upload any file size. When i tried file size of 22 MB, It worked. But When I tried 200MB file, it seems it does not entered in if block and return me the output of else block after taking all the time in the world to upload file.
My work on this is mention below. Am I missing something?

HTML:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal"  role="form">
<label for="document">Upload your Document</label>
<input type="file" id="document" name="document">
<label for="doc_cat">Document Category:</label>
<select name="doc_cat" id="doc_cat" class="form-control" required>
<option value="">--Select a Category--</option>
<option value="1">Sales</option>
<option value="2">Technical</option>
<option value="3">Pricing</option>
<option value="4">Policies</option>
<option value="5">Other</option>
</select>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="upload" name="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

JQUERY/AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#upload').click(function () {
            var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);
            var that = this;
            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload-document-proccess.php',  //Server script to process data
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                async: false,
                beforeSend: function() {
                      $("#loading-image").show();
                },
                success: function (msg) {
                    $("#loading-image").hide();
                    $("#display-return-msg").html(msg);
                    $("#display-return-msg").fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
        $('form')[0].reset();
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

upload-document-proccess.php:

```
if(isset($_POST) && $_FILES['document']['size'] > 0)
{
    $category_id = $_POST['doc_cat'];
    $doc_desc = htmlspecialchars($_POST['doc_desc'],ENT_QUOTES);
    switch ($category_id) {
        case 1:
            $category="Sales";
            break;
        case 2:
            $category="Technical";
            break;
        case 3:
            $category="Pricing";
            break;
        case 4:
            $category="Policies";
            break;
        case 5:
            $category="Other";
            break;
        default:
            # code...
            break;
    }

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["document"]["name"]);

    $fileName = $_FILES['document']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['document']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['document']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['document']['type'];

    $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content = addslashes($content);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["document"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $msg = "The file ". basename( $_FILES["document"]["name"]). " has been uploaded to ".$category." Category";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
    fclose($fp);

    if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {
        $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    }

    try {   
        $sql = "INSERT INTO document (doc_name, doc_type, doc_size, user_id, doc_category_id, doc_date, doc_desc)
        VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileType', '$fileSize', '$user_id', '$category_id', now(), '$doc_desc')";
        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);
        ?><script type="text/javascript">
        var msg = '<?php echo $msg; ?>';
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#display-return-msg").html(msg);
                $("#display-return-msg").fadeIn("slow").delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
            });
        </script>
        <?php
        }
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
        }
    //echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";   
}else{
    echo "Please select File to upload.";
}
?>
```

In '#display-return-msg' id, It gives me "Please select File to upload" when i uploaded 200MB file. When i uploaded 22 MB file, I got value of 'msg' variable which is correct. Please suggest me What do i do?

Comment: Check in php.ini what is the value for `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` and increase the limit and then check?

Comment: I tried uploading 66MB file it gives me  "Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted". That means post_max_size is 128 MB. But if read it carefully, it throws me to else loop when i upload 200MB file.

Answer (score 3):

there are a lot of settings that could restrict the filesize of your upload. here is an example based on an XAMPP installation on windows. but it should be quite similar on linux.
found at http://mewbies.com/how_to_install_setup_apache_xampp.htm:

> TO CHANGE SIZE OF FILES ALLOWED TO UPLOAD:
>
> To allow large file uploads you must change the settings on your PHP &     Apache conf files, we'll use
>   600MB file size as the example, change it to  your own needs:
>   Edit this file: D:\xampp\php\php.ini
>
> Search for: upload_max_filesize
>   Change
>   to:
>   upload_max_filesize = 600M
>
> Search for: post_max_size
>   Has this:
>   post_max_size = 8M
>   Change to (it must be larger than upload_max_filesize):
>   post_max_size = 700M
>
> Search for: memory_limit
>   Has this: memory_limit = 128M
>   Change to, if you don't want any limit:
>   memory_limit = -1
>   Or change to (it must be larger than post_max_size):
>   memory_limit = 800M
>
> Search for: max_execution_time
>   Has this: max_execution_time = 30
>   Change to for example:
>   max_execution_time = 9600
>
> Search for (just below max_execution_time): max_input_time = 60
>   Has this: max_input_time = 60
>   Change to: max_input_time =3600
>
> Done, save the changes.
>
> Edit this file: D:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-default.conf
>   Search for: LimitRequestBody
>   If your conf does not have this line; add it
>   Has this: LimitRequestBody 102400
>   Change to:
>   LimitRequestBody 600000000
>
> you set it to 0, meaning unlimited up to 2147483647 bytes (2GB)
>
> Restart your web server.

Comment: It is in production not local host, so i dont think i 'll have access to php.ini file or conf files. Is it possible programmatically?

Comment: @KetanJoshi depends what privileges you got on the server. if you got the privileges you can also override `php.ini` settings with [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

Answer (score 0):

you can test like at the very first line use this line

```
echo phpinfo();exit;
```

and find and check 'max_file_uploads' if it does have less than your requirement increase it by writing at the very first of page

```
ini_set('max_file_uploads', 'as per your need size')
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any query or doubt .

Comment: Actually it is working code. Only thing is it is not working when i upload large files. as of now I have tested uploading 22M, which is working fine. For 66M you  see main question's comment, I have mention what error it gives and when i upload extra large file like 199MB, It is giving me result of else block of the my .php file.
Second, I also dont only want to upload image file type. There can be videos, pdfs and zip files almost all files.

Comment: ok got the point so you can test like at the very first line use this line         echo phpinfo();exit; and find and check 'max_file_uploads' if it does have less than your requirement increase it by writing at the very first of page    ini_set('max_file_uploads', 'as per your need size');

Answer (score 0):

To upload large files to web server, need to modify some settings (using .htaccess) in the php. Two php configuration options, the maximum upload size: upload_max_filesize and post_max_size. Both can be set to, say, "200M" for 200 megabyte file sizes.

Comment: I tried this, plain as you written. But it is saying that page is not found on the server. It will be great if you help me with syntax. If i am missing something.
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 200M
I have tried this.

Comment: #set max post size
php_value post_max_size 200M
#set upload max filesize
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M

Answer (score -1):

You need to increase upload limit in php.ini file

EDITED: You should ask host to allow you owerwrite php ini configuration for upload limit, if they do this for you will be able to do this, if they can't or don't want you wont be able to to this.

After they enable this you can:

```
1.create local copy of php.ini in folder where is script which performs upload
2.you can do it in code, example for turning of erro reporting:
error_reporting(-1);
3.you can set this in cpanel for this account if is possible/enabled.
```

Comment: It is not possible as site is in production. Not the localhost.